# How to end a sub thread which has Dispatcher call inside

Tags: wpf

I'm building an application that continuously pull data from device and update to UI.

Once I click a Start button, a sub-thread is created with a while loop inside, that read data from device every 200ms, then I call dispatcher.invoke to update this value to GUI.

```
while(true)
{
    if (!IsPowerOn)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("background thread else exit"); 
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            if (session.IsDisposed || session == null) break;
                session.RawIO.Write("MEAS:VOLT?\r");
                var volt = session.RawIO.ReadString();                    
                Dispatcher.Invoke(() => VoltOutput = float.Parse(volt));
                Console.WriteLine(volt);
    
            if (session.IsDisposed || session == null) break;
                session.RawIO.Write("MEAS:CURR?\r");
                var curr = session.RawIO.ReadString();
                Console.WriteLine(curr);
                Action<string> action1 = delegate (string s) { CurrOutput = float.Parse(s); };
                Dispatcher.Invoke(action1, curr);
            
                Thread.Sleep(200);
                Console.WriteLine("sleep");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            session.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("background thread except exit");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

In the main thread, if I click Stop button, IsPower = false; thread.join(); is called. but this will cause program stuck. It seems dispatcher is stucked here. Don't know is dispatcher terminated abormally or still working. either way, main thread is not respond to thread.join.

hope anyone can give me some clue on this or a common practice for app like this

Thanks

Comment: Why are you calling `Join()`? This will deadlock your app.

Comment: @mm8 i'd like to stop sub-thread, which is continuously querying result and dispatcher/update to UI. and first statement i come up with is thread.join.....

Comment: Setting `IsPowerOn` to `false` should be enough to eventually exit the loop and finish the thread.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a deadlock. In the bg thread you expect the GUI thread handle `Dispatcher.Invoke` but GUI thread being blocked in the event handler of `Button.Click` through `thread.join()`.

To avoid you can

- fire&forget `Dispatcher.InvokeAsync`
- OR make event handler `Button.Click` `async` and call `await Task.Run(()=>{thread.join();});`
- OR do not call `thread.join()` / do not wait the thread is finished. You could check thread status in another parts of program logic, to be sure the thread is finished.

I don't know how fast the data fetching is, but to make stop more responsive you could try to add check for `IsPowerOn` to each `(session.IsDisposed || session == null)` and also before `Thread.Sleep`.